# Camel JMS - Unable to set JMSPriority to IBM MQ Message

Tags: apache-camel, ibm-mq

We are trying to send JMS text message over IBM mq using Apache Camel. We are able set few JMS header properties except the JMSPriority. We tried setting int value and used resultType="java.lang.Integer" but unable to alter priority. Any clue would be more than helpful.

```
 <route id="mqSender">
                 <from uri="direct:mqSender"></from>
                 <filter>
                       <simple> ${body} != null</simple>
                       <setProperty propertyName="originalRequest">
                              <simple> ${body}</simple>
                       </setProperty>
                       <setHeader headerName="JMSCorrelationID">
                              <simple>${body.messageContextVO.requestID}</simple>
                       </setHeader>
                       <setHeader headerName="VersionId">
                              <simple>${body.metadata["VersionId"]}</simple>
                       </setHeader>
                       <setHeader headerName="FunctionId">
                              <simple>${body.metadata["FunctionId"]}</simple>
                       </setHeader>
                       <setHeader headerName="Format">
                              <simple>${body.metadata["Format"]}</simple>
                       </setHeader>
                       <choice>
                              <when>
                                     <simple>${property.originalRequest.metadata["FetchPriorityValue"]}== "true"</simple>
                                     <transform>
                                            <simple>${body.formattedData}</simple>
                                     </transform>
                                     <setHeader headerName="JMSPriority">
                                           <simple> ${property.originalRequest.priority}</simple>
                                     </setHeader>

                                     <camel:setHeader headerName="CamelJmsDestinationName"><simple>queue:///${property.originalRequest.metadata["queueName"]}?targetClient=1</simple></camel:setHeader>

                              </when>
                       </choice>
                      <log message="${property.originalRequest.metadata[queueName]}"></log>
                       <recipientList>
                              <simple>wmq:queue:${property.originalRequest.metadata["queueName"]}?exchangePattern=InOnly</simple>
                       </recipientList>
                       <transform>
                              <simple>${property.originalRequest}</simple>
                       </transform>
                 </filter>
                 <!-- <to uri="bean:trackerUpdateProcessor?method=process" /> -->
          </route>
```

Answer (score 1):

We found solution to make it work. Priority attribute is required to set at header CamelJmsDestinationName
i.e,

```
<camel:setHeader headerName="CamelJmsDestinationName"><simple>queue:///${property.originalRequest.metadata["queueName"]}?targetClient=1&amp;priority=${dynamicValue}</simple></camel:setHeader>
```

Sender code checks for value of priority at MQ Destination level in native code. TimeToLive and Priority values needs to set at MQ destination level to work with Camel.

Comment: Did you try setting just the targetClient=1 on the destination setting and use the endpoint settings for QoS?

Comment: Yes but it didn't work out. Along with it, setting priority attribute worked out.

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure about wmq, but for normal jms component (and I believe camel wmq behave the same) to set JMSPriority for specific message endpoint configuration must have option "preserveMessageQos" set to true

> Set to true, if you want to send message using the QoS settings specified on the message, instead of the QoS settings on the JMS endpoint. The following three headers are considered JMSPriority, JMSDeliveryMode, and JMSExpiration. You can provide all or only some of them. If not provided, Camel will fall back to use the values from the endpoint instead. So, when using this option, the headers override the values from the endpoint. The explicitQosEnabled option, by contrast, will only use options set on the endpoint, and not values from the message header.

Comment: We tried enabling preserveQoS . while debugging we found that even Camel set those values to JMS message, native mq code overides that with check inside in it.

Comment: This solution worked for me. Setting the preserveMessageQos=true on the endPoint at the JMS client level enable JMSPriority to be preserved and configurable.
Before all messsages had JMSPriority set to 4 even when I was setting the value in the message header.  Now by default priority is 0 except if you specifically set the header value to the one you wish.