# How to set priority of IBM MQ message through REST API?

Tags: rest, ibm-mq

I'm trying to put a message onto an IBM MQ queue through the REST API, but I can't figure out how to set the priority in the request. I've tried simply using "priority" as a query parameter but received the following error:

```
"error": [
        {
            "action": "Resubmit the request with an appropriate set of parameters.",
            "completionCode": 0,
            "explanation": "The REST API does not support this query parameter for this operation.",
            "message": "MQWB0019E: The query parameter 'priority' is not allowed.",
            "msgId": "MQWB0019E",
            "reasonCode": 0,
            "type": "rest"
        }
    ]
```

[Question 36399382](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36399382/camel-jms-unable-to-set-jmspriority-to-ibm-mq-message) mentioned using both the "priority" and "targetClient" query parameters, but that seems specific to Apache Camel, and even trying it, it didn't work.

I've looked through all of the IBM MQ REST API documentation I can find, but nothing that I've come across addresses it. I'm sure there's some documentation somewhere, but I'm just not finding it. Is this something specific that has to be configured on the server, or is there a problem with my syntax?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The messaging REST API, that is HTTP POST to `/messaging/qmgr/{qmgrName}/queue/{queueName}/message` does not currently include a header for setting the priority of the message.

It includes headers for `correlationId`, `expiry`, `persistence`, and `ReplyTo`. See the [reference material here](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSFKSJ_9.1.0/com.ibm.mq.ref.dev.doc/q130750_.htm).

If you have requests that need to set different priorities, you could create different ALIAS Queue definitions with different values for the `DEFPRTY` attribute, all pointing to the same LOCAL Queue, and have your REST API applications use the appropriate ALIAS queue name in order to have the priority set to what they need.

**UPDATE:** The v3 MQ REST API, that is HTTP POST to `/ibmmq/rest/v3/messaging/qmgr/{qmgrName}/queue/{queueName}/message` now supports a header in order to set the priority of the message. This was introduced in IBM MQ V9.2.5.

Use the header `ibm-mq-md-priority`, for example like this:-

```
curl -X POST https://localhost:9443/ibmmq/rest/v3/messaging/qmgr/MQG1/queue/MY.QUEUE/message -H "Content-Type: text/plain" -d "My message" -H "ibm-mq-md-priority: 9"
```

Comment: Thanks for the confirmation that I wasn't missing it! :-)

Comment: @blackpaladin - glad to be able to help. Remember to accept the answer if it solved your problem